# How to serialize a instance of third party java class into protobuf in akka

Tags: akka, akka-cluster, protobuf-java

currently,  I'm sending Java class object as message to Scala Akka Actors.

The java classes are generated from json which is [here](https://github.com/openrtb/openrtb2x/blob/2.0/openrtb-validator/src/main/resources/schemas/openrtb-schema_bid-request_v2-5.json).

So I have limited access to change anything related to this class.

Right now the messages are serialized using akka default serializer which io.Serializable.

I want to migrate this to protobuf but not sure how could I do this with my third party BidRequest.java class

Comment: Take a look at the [reference.conf](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/d41622296e1d652836860beeeaca4b9a4d6f2083/akka-remote/src/main/resources/reference.conf#L46) of [akka-remote](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/remoting.html). It adds the serializer for protobuf classes and it should be picked up automatically.

Comment: My question is for non protobuf java classes. The generated sample is https://gist.github.com/rajcspsg/c3f431ae54b04f01cd2a3861f13daf74.